# Retrieve data that have similar values in one column

Tags: r

I have the following dataset:

```
Class       Value
Drive       9.5
Analyser    6.35
GameGUI     12.09
Drive       9.5
Analyser    5.5
GameGUI     2.69
Drive       9.5
Analyser    9.10
GameGUI     6.1
```

I want to retrieve the classes that have similar values, which would be in the case of the example above is `Drive`. To do that I have the following command:

```
dataset[as.logical(ave(dataset$Value, dataset$Class, FUN = function(x) all(x==1))), ]
```

But this command returns only the classes that their values is always one. What I want is different, I don't want to give a specific value.

Comment: `duplicated()`?

Comment: wrong use of the word similar. 9.5 and 9.5 are NOT similar. They are equal/ the same/ identical.

Comment: as pointed out before, `duplicated()` is the way to go - `x[duplicated(x),]`

Comment: Here is a defition from google: `"Similar": 1.
having a resemblance in appearance, character, or quantity, without being identical.`